# singular or plural: "cost of repair" or "cost of repairs" or "cost of a repair"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I have made up the sentences below.

(1) When a refrigerator stops working, I buy a new one because the cost of repair can be very high.

(2) When a refrigerator stops working, I buy a new one because the cost of repair**S** can be very high.

(3) When a refrigerator stops working, I buy a new one because the cost of **a** repair can be very high.

I am not sure which one is correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd accept any of these options.  Repair can be treated as both count or non count.  So it is possible to use a singular without an article, singular with an article or plural.